# Probability of a given 5 letter word occurring at a given position in 1000000 randomly typed letters.

Tags: probability

The problem specifically is to compute the probability of a word "broom" appearing at a given position in a random string of 10^6 letters.

My first instinct is to just calculate the probability as (1/26)^5 but here the problem is that if the word does appear in position i, then it must not have appeared in the four positions before and after i. I think that this would lead to an overcount. How do I compute the probability now that I am aware of this relationship?

Comment: Is the question about the prob. that the word "broom" appears **at least** once in a random string of $10^6$ letters?

Comment: "but here the problem is that if the word does appear in position i, then it must not have appeared in the four positions before and after i"  Well as "?broo", "??bro", "???br", "????b", "room?", "oom??", "om???" and "m????" are all different from "broom". if "broom" occurs in the $i$th position that alone would assure it is *impossible* for "broom" to occur in the four positions before or after.

Comment: It doesn't matter what *any* of the characters between $0...., i-1$ or $i+5, ....10^6$ are or whether or not the word "broom" occurs or doesn't occur in any of those positions.  The *only* thing you are being asked is do the letters $b,r,o,o,m$ occur in positions $i,i+1,i+2,i+3$ and $i+4$ respectively.  And the probability of that is $\frac 1{26^5}$.

Comment: Your answer is correct, as pointed out by fleablood.

Comment: @callculus yes and no. I also need to calculate this and then I will proceed to attempt doing what you mentioned on my own.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the response.